# Subversion hook updating externals autentification error

Tags: svn, post-commit, svn-hooks, externals

I have a post-commit hook that is updating a working copy.
In that working copy some of the files are externals witch have authentication.
Is there a way to pass the login credentials to the svn update only for the externals ?

Right now it does the update but because the external asks for login, it fails to update the external library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not separately.

One way of getting the credentials available to the Subversion client is to log in as that user, say with sudo or su, and manually do a checkout from all the web sites into /tmp so they get stored.  Then the client running during the post-commit should work.